# If $A,B,C\in L(X)$ commutes, then $A\leq B,$ and $C\geq 0$ follows $AC\leq BC.$

Tags: functional-analysis

I do not very well understand functional analysis but this discipline is seems interesting, so some examples of post on this site with the hope that many participants in this site are willing to help me,

*If $A,B,C\in L(X)$ commutes, then $A\leq B,$ and $C\geq 0$ follows $AC\leq BC.$*

Please help me prove the given theorem. Thanky very much for your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the definition of positive operators? You can solve it by its definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very well do you Interested in functional analysis but only to know that mathematics is a discipline which is not very easy, ie., it's very difficult.

I understand a little of functional analysis, and know that there are some answers to your example, but my answer to this is like the following example:

From $B-A\geq 0,$ $C\geq 0,$ and $(B-A)C=C(B-A)$.

Now this theorem: *If $A,B\in L(X)$ is positive semidefinition hermitian operators and if they commutes, then $AB$ is positive semidefinition hermitian operator.*

we have:
$$(B-A)C\geq 0.$$

I hope I helped you. I wish you luck.